# How to extract the extension point which is set to an extend relation between use cases in Enterprise Architect using the API

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a Usecase diagram which has usecases having extends relationship. I want to know if there is any API which can be used to know what extension point is set to a specific extends relation (out of many extension points that can be applied). The Usecase diagram along with the Extension Point highlighted is shown below. [image]

Comment: I would guess this is a manually filled note. Or are you using any new post 13.5 EA feature here?

Comment: Right click on the connector (with <<extends>> stereotype) -> Advanced -> Extension Point -> Set Extension Point. This will give a set of extension points that are defined for a usecase, from which we can choose one.  This will come up as a note with a stereotype  automatically.

Comment: @qwerty_so I think it's always been possible to define extension points and assign extension points to an extend relation. Not that many people use it. But then again, I haven't seen many extends being used correctly at all.

Comment: Yes. There is. Right click on UC -> Advanced -> Edit Extension Point (Add any number of EPs)

Comment: As said: never used it. I now found how to add the EP. But how is the note created?

Comment: After defining an EP for a UC, follow the steps in comment 2 above.

Comment: Please check if the 'show extension point' is checked in the same menu where you set the extension point to the extends relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this being a standard note and not some fancy new EA feature you can find such a note with a simple query:

```
SELECT note as n FROM t_object WHERE pdata4 = "idref1=<connectorID>"
```

where `<connectorID>` needs to be the connector's id in question. That will return the text written in the note. Just use Repository.SQLQuery to pass that to EA. You need to unwrap the returned XML in whatwever language you use (I'm using my Python framework which does that and returns a row array of column arrays).

**Edit** Having found how to create such a note the above still is valid. However, it seems that EA also sets the `name` of the element to `#EXP#<objectID>`. So you could likely use that as search criterion as well.

Comment: Does ';' in the pdata4 exists only for extension points? for other type of notes for the connectors, the ';' is not there.

Comment: Oops. That was my imagination which put it there. I have fixed the answer.